# POST form parameters with Unfiltered

Tags: forms, scala, post, unfiltered

I have problem extracting form parameters (in body) from POST with Unfiltered.

From http://unfiltered.databinder.net/Within+the+Parameters.html I understood that Params(p) would put into p both url parameters and also form parameters inside body. But I just can't get form parameters in body.

Of course I could take body as string and build parser for that, but it would just be silly as would expect there would be something ready for such basic operation ...but I just can't find it.

My service is following and it prints out any parameters from url but not form-data parameters, if I use x-www-form-urlencoded then it seems to works.

```
def intent {
  case POST(ContextPath(_, Seg("accounts" :: "providers" :: AsLong(id) :: "mfa" :: Nil)) & Params(params)) ⇒
    println(s"${params.mkString("\n")}")
    Ok
}
```

Comment: Please post the action code, the form mapping especially and the route you are using.

Comment: Updated question. So I can get url encoded form parameters but not one in body. I can now live with that but would be nice to know if there is some way for using also multipart/form-data mode